# How to bash-complete output of two arbitrary commands at the same time

Tags: bash

Here goes:

```
function _command() {
    local cur
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    if [ "$COMP_CWORD" -ge "2" ]; then
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '$(pwd)' -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "arg1 arg2" -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
}
complete -F _command command
```

This works well, so long as I `source` it.

What if I want it to auto-complete both outputs of `pwd` and some other arbitrary command, say `hostname`? What if I also wanted it to auto-complete on any file path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986023/bash-combine-two-arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '$(pwd)' -- "$cur") $(compgen -W '$(hostname)' -- "$cur"))
```

(you want a bigger array, just make one) or

```
COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '$(pwd; hostname)' -- "$cur" ) )
```

(still autocompleting one command).

Comment: For the first example, something like `$( compgen -o default -- "$cur")` does what I wanted... see my question edit.